# Bash: printf and sed

Tags: bash, sed, printf

I cannot wrap my head around this...

Why does this construct not work:

```bash
printf -v REGEX "%s\\|" "string1" "string2"
REPLACE="blabla"

sed "s/${REGEX}/${REPLACE}/" file1 > file2
```

But this works:

```bash
REGEX="string1\|string2\|"
REPLACE="blabla"

sed "s/${REGEX}/${REPLACE}/" file1 > file2
```

`printf` creates the same string as the one in the second example, yet sed cannot substitute it. Instead, it  places the `REPLACE` string at the beginning of every line in `file2`.

Comment: FYI, all-caps variable names are reserved; you should be using at least one lower-case character for your own variable names.

Comment: also, the backslashes are simply wrong.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, if you want a reference for the variable-capitalization thing. (That reference is specifically for environment variables, but they share a namespace with shell variables, so conventions apply in both cases).

Comment: Care to explain that?

Comment: ...basically, any environment variable whose name is valid as a shell variable automatically becomes a shell variable as well -- and *changing* the value of such a shell variable modifies value of any overlapping environment variable as well. Thus, to avoid overwriting environment variables with meaning to other components of the system, it's appropriate to follow those conventions in interacting with shell variables as well.

Comment: The regexp created by `printf` looks like `string1\|string2\|`. That's not the same as your second example.

Comment: @Barmar you're right that was an error in my comment. Editing

Comment: @charles I meant care to explain the backlashes being wrong?

Comment: Ahh! I meant exactly what I said; the only OR operator available is `|` (which, itself, is only in ERE). `\|` is a GNU extension, not supported by standard BRE (that is, the POSIX basic regex syntax, which is what `sed` uses without `-r`); the better approach is to use `sed -r`, to make ERE syntax (in which `|` needs no backslash to work) available.

Comment: Yeah but I am on gnu and need the script only for gnu! :) Thx for the quick tips, I just didn't realize that `printf` is leaving a trailing `\|`. I need coffe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider instead:

```
printf -v regex '%s|' string1 string2
sed -r -e "s/${regex%|}/$replace/" file1 > file2
```

This works because it removes the trailing `|` from the regex, preventing it from matching the empty string.

Comment: You also need to remove the backslash before the `|`.

Comment: It was meant for you, to fix your answer.

Comment: OK, this answers it then. I'll delete my answers here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't realize you changed the `printf` as well.